# Uploading File in DAM Programmatically using AssetManager? What MimeType should I use?

Tags: java, mime-types, aem, sling

I have a form that uploads a File to a SlingServlet. The SlingSerlvet receives the file and it tries to save the file in DAM using com.day.cq.dam.api.AssetManager.(i.e. **Save file in DAM programmatically)**

The problem arises with MIME types. The user may upload a pdf,xls, doc etc. so the Type is not fixed. I don't know what to set the MIME type as(see the third parameter xxx)  `assetMgr.createAsset(newFile, is,"xxx", true);`

I tried **"application/octet-stream"**   but CQ ignores the Type saying asset ignored.

Log:

```
27.11.2014 18:58:48.595 *INFO* [JobHandler: /etc/workflow/instances/2014-11-27/model_879500607401687:/content/dam/videojetdocuments/videojetdocuments/offerletters/Präsentation_Dominik_Suess.pdf/jcr:content/renditions/original] com.day.cq.dam.video.FFMpegThumbnailProcess execute: asset [/content/dam/videojetdocuments/videojetdocuments/offerletters/Präsentation_Dominik_Suess.pdf] is not of a video mime type, asset ignored.
27.11.2014 18:58:48.596 *INFO* [JobHandler: /etc/workflow/instances/2014-11-27/model_879500607401687:/content/dam/videojetdocuments/videojetdocuments/offerletters/Präsentation_Dominik_Suess.pdf/jcr:content/renditions/original] com.day.cq.dam.video.FFMpegTranscodeProcess execute: asset [/content/dam/videojetdocuments/videojetdocuments/offerletters/Präsentation_Dominik_Suess.pdf] is not of a video mime type, asset ignored.
```

I tried this using the following [**link**](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/uploading-files-aem1.html)

**Is there any generic MIME Type for such type of Files?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Apache Sling [MimeTypeService](http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/commons/mime/MimeTypeService.html) to compute the mimetype based on an incoming filename. See also http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/mime-type-support-commons-mime.html

If you don't have the filename you'll need something like the [Apache Tika Detector](http://tika.apache.org/1.4/detection.html), which analyzes the binary to try to guess its mimetype. I don't know if CQ provides such a service out of the box, but if it doesn't you could integrate it yourself.

**Edit:**

API that checks the MIMEType based on Magic headers [Link](http://mime-util.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html)

Helpful link for understanding the above mentioned problem [Link](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html)

Comment: I don't want to check MimeType with file name and extention that is lame. So I am trying open source API's that  Check MimeType based on Magic Headers. Apache Tika is too huge and required a lot of other jars as well.

Comment: It worked however I did not use Apache Tika due to its heavy dependencies. I used something called as MimeUtil. It checks the MimeType based on Magic Headers. Link in Answer. Great job Bertnard

Comment: Thanks for the useful references!